# Include parents JSON ignored fields

Tags: jackson

I want to include JSON ignored properties of parent class inside the child class for JSON serialization.

I tried to annotate the child fields with `@JsonInclude` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just annotate the fields with @JsonProperty and give the name of the property.

### Parent

```java
@JsonIgnore
private boolean emailVerified;
@JsonIgnore
private List<RoleDTO> roles;
```

### Child

```java
@JsonProperty("emailVerified")
private boolean emailVerified;
@JsonProperty("roles")
private List<RoleDTO> roles;
```

### Output

[image: JSON output]